# How to create a square box in which the border of the box will be filled by color depending on the value given on the box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

[image: 1]

Just like the above image or an idea or reference to achieve this design, I appreciate the help or suggestion given by community thank you

I have got reference of progress bar which is circular but not able find an approach to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'violet']
boxes.forEach((box) => {
  const insideContent = box.innerText;
  box.style.border = `6px solid ${colors[insideContent]}`
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: cyan;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

As per your question I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First define a pseudo class root

```
:root {
  --color-val: blue;
}
```

Note: In order to use the `--color-val` you need to write it as `color: var(--color-var)` in CSS

---

Second use JavaScript to update the variable `--color-val`

```
let colors = 
    
var root = document.querySelector(':root');

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const colorChange = async () => {
  await delay(1000);
  color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  console.log(color)
  root.style.setProperty('--color-val', color);
};

colorChange()
```

Note:

- Add the color list you want to select from or go to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hatguy68/pen/NWBPQaM) for a list of 1000+ hex codes.
- Promise are used for asynchronous function and can be skipped by using setTimeOut for a delayed loop or if used with another eventlistener.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I misunderstood the question. Wrote in a hurry and without beautyful visualisation, if you disassemble the principle, you can customize it.

```css
h1 {
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;  
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:20%;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 110;
  margin:0;
  margin: -10px;
  
}

.top {
  display:block;
  background-color: green;
  height: 24px;
  width: 150px; /* gorizontal top */
  
    animation: top 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes top {
    0% {
        width: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 150px;
    }
}

.right {

  background-color: green;
  height: 0%;/* right */
  width: 32px;
  
  animation: right 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;  
  
  z-index: 10;
  
}

@keyframes right {
    0% {
        height: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
    }
}




.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 32.5px;
  left: 32.5px;
  
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 120;
  margin: -10px -10px;

}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 123px;
  left: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 0px;
  height: 27px;
  
  z-index: 10;
  
    animation: bottom 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  /* animation-direction: reverse; */
  
}

@keyframes bottom {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-250px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-250px,0); /** Safari & Chrome **/
    -o-transform: translate(-250px,0); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(-250px,0); /** Firefox **/
    width: 250px;
    }
}


.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 122px;
  
  
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 0px;
  
  animation: left 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  
  
}

@keyframes left {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0,-250px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-250px); /** Safari & Chrome **/
    -o-transform: translate(0,-250px); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-250px); /** Firefox **/
    height: 277px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='head'>


<div class='container'>
  <div class='top'></div>
  <div class='box'>
    <h1 id='timer'>
    1
    </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class='right'></div>
  <div class='bottom'></div>
  <div class='left'></div>
</div>

</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 init()
            function init()
            {
                sec = 0;
                setInterval(tick, 1000);
            }
            
            function tick()
            {       if (sec<3) { sec++
                document.getElementById("timer").
                    childNodes[0].nodeValue = sec;
                    } else {
                    clearInterval(0);
                    }
            }
</script>
```

Also, instead of the SetInterval script, you can take values from your block width and height styles and output a mathematical calculation in h1 instead of a stopwatch.

**upd:** After your comment, I decided to do what I wrote about above. You can play with values and math, I add a snippet of another solution that changes the progress bar from the entered values within the entered range. (of course, it would be easier on react than on pure js)

```js
function grade () {
let grade = +document.getElementById("grade").value;
let range = +document.getElementById("range").value;
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = `${grade}/${range}`;
progress(grade,range)
}

  function progress (value, grade) {
  
  document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundColor = `white`
  document.getElementById("left").className = "noactive";
  document.getElementById('top').style.width = `0%`
  document.getElementById('right').style.height = `0%`
  document.getElementById('bottom').style.width = `0%`
  
  let GradeValuSide = grade/4;
  
  if (value <= GradeValuSide) { 
  
    document.getElementById('top').style.width = 
    `${value/GradeValuSide*100}%`
    
   } else if (value > GradeValuSide && value <= (GradeValuSide*2)) {
   
    document.getElementById('top').style.width = `100%`
    document.getElementById('right').style.height = 
    `${(value-GradeValuSide)/GradeValuSide*100}%`
    
  } else if (value >= grade/2 && value < (grade/4)*3) {
 
    document.getElementById('top').style.width = `100%`
    document.getElementById('right').style.height = `100%`
    document.getElementById('bottom').style.width = 
    `${((((value-(GradeValuSide*2)) / GradeValuSide) *100) / 100) *27}%`
    
  } else if (value >= grade-(grade/4) /* && value < value + 1 */) {
    document.getElementById('top').style.width = `100%`
    document.getElementById('right').style.height = `100%`
    document.getElementById('bottom').style.width = `100%`
   document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundColor = `green`
    document.getElementById("left").className = "left";
       
    document.getElementById('left').style.height = 
    `${(40 - (40 * ((((value-(GradeValuSide*3)) * 100) / GradeValuSide)/ 100)))}%`

 }
 }
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size:20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;  
  align-items: center;
  padding-top:10%;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:0;
  margin: -10px;
}

div.top {
  display:block;
  background-color: green;
  height: 24px;
  width: 0%; /* gorizontal top */
  z-index:999;
}

div.right {
  position:relative;

  background-color: green;
  height: 0%;/* right */
  width: 32px;
  z-index: 9999;
}




.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 32.5px;
  left: 32.5px;
  background-color:white;
  
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 120;
  margin: -10px -10px;

}

.wrap{
  position: relative;
}

div.bottom {
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 123px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 0%; /* 27 = 100% */
  height: 27px;

  float: right;
  right: 78vw;

  z-index: 100;
  
}

div.left {
  position: absolute;
 
  
  background-color: white;
  width: 23px;
  height: 40%;
  
  top: 23px;
   
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 0;
   float: top;
}

div.noactive {
   position: absolute;
 
  
  background-color: white;
  width: 23px;
  height: 0%;
  
  top: 23px;
   
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 0;
   float: top;  
}

.items {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grade,
.value {
  
  height: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='head'>


<div id='1' class='container'>
  <div id='top' class='top'></div>
  <div class='box'>
    <h1 id='timer'>1</h1>
      <div class='items'>
         value<input id='grade' class='grade' type=number oninput="grade()"/>
         
         range<input id='range' class='value' type=number oninput="grade()"/>
  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='right' class='right'></div>
  <div id='bottom' class='bottom'></div>
  
  <div id='left' class='noactive'></div>
  
</div>
</div>



<script src='app.js'></script>
```

Comment: It is somewhat same but it's like a counter or progress but depending on the value like if there are 36 question and 20 are answered so they inner value which is displayed is 20, and 36 will be like hundred percent of the border in which 20 will be 55% which will be filled in border.

Comment: @shashi, ok, as I wrote above, instead of SetInterval, you can play with values, added a new snippet to the solution. Look please.